# Why isn't my BouncyBall object moving on-screen in Visual Basic?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to code a bouncing ball application in Visual Basic 2010. I have two classes: one is for building the ball object and moving the balls, and I have a ball class with the location and speed of the ball.

My main class:

```
Public Class Bouncer 'start of main class

    Private ball As BouncyBall 'private ball object field

    'form load event handler
    Private Sub CST8333_Lab3_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ball = New BouncyBall(Me) 'call ball constructor
    End Sub 'end form load event handler

    'timer event handler to control ball movement
    Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
        ball.MoveBall() 'move the ball object
    End Sub 'end timer event handler
End Class 'end main class
```

My ball class:

```
Class BouncyBall 'start of ball class

    'private field variables
    Private ballX As Integer
    Private ballY As Integer
    Private ballMovementX As Integer
    Private ballMovementY As Integer
    Private location As Point
    Private _bouncer As Bouncer

    'ball object constructor
    Sub New(bouncer As Bouncer)
        'instantiate variables
        _bouncer = bouncer
        ballX = 50
        ballY = 50
        ballMovementX = 5
        ballMovementY = 5
        location = New Point(ballX, ballY)
    End Sub 'end ball object constructor

    'subroutine to move ball
    Public Sub MoveBall()
        If (ballX >= _bouncer.Width) Then 'check if ball hits right side
            ballMovementX = -ballMovementX
        ElseIf (ballX <= 0) Then 'check if ball hits left side
            ballMovementX = -ballMovementX
        End If
        If (ballY >= _bouncer.Height) Then 'check if ball hits bottom
            ballMovementY = -ballMovementY
        ElseIf (ballY <= 0) Then 'check if ball hits top
            ballMovementY = -ballMovementY
        End If
        'move ball
        ballX += ballMovementX
        ballY += ballMovementY
        Me.location = New Point(ballX, ballY)
    End Sub 'end subroutine to move ball
End Class 'end ball class
```

The ball object consists of a label moving around the form. The ball object is called BouncyBall and I want the rules in my MoveBall() subroutine to guide the ball around the form.
However, my ball does not move at all. My timer is enabled, and has an interval of 50 ms, so that is not my issue. I think my issue is my MoveBall() rules use variables that don't actually update the properties of my label.

After finding a way to use my variables to update the location of my BouncyBall ball, my ball still is not moving. I still think I need to somehow link my BouncyBall class, containing my rules, to the actual Label on the form (which is also called BouncyBall).

Can anybody help me get my ball to move? I'm starting to run out of ideas. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose your Bouncer or BouncyBall classes are inherited from somewhere. Which is the parent class?

Comment: Parent class is Bouncer.